# Decimal Field Converts Zero to 0E-8

Tags: apex

Why doesn't the below just display zero? Instead I'm getting `0E-8`

```
    Decimal spend = 0.00;
    Decimal convertType = 1.000000;
    system.debug('Calculate: ' +  spend * convertType);
```

> USER_DEBUG [94]|DEBUG|Calculate: 0E-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening here is that the scale of two `Decimal` values is additive when you multiply them. So you take a `Decimal` with scale 2 and a `Decimal` with scale 6, you end up with a `Decimal` of scale 8.

If you call `setScale` you can get a more normal result. Note, however, that `0E-8 == 0` is still true.

```
Decimal spend = 0.00;
Decimal conversionRate = 1.000000;
Decimal value = spend * conversionRate;
system.debug(value == 0); // outputs true
system.debug(value.scale()); // outputs 8
system.debug(value.setScale(2)); // outputs 0.00
```